# Many clients using different computers java chatbox

Tags: java, sockets

I am making a simple java chatbox using sockets. When I run many clients on same computer, everything's alright, but when I try it on different PCs, they don't share the information. How could I fix that? I guess that has something to do with port and host, not sure though. My connecting method is below.

```
 public static void Connect() {

    try {
        final int port = 444;
        String hostname = "";
        try
        {
            InetAddress addr;
            addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            hostname = addr.getHostName();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Hostname can not be resolved");
        }
        final String host = "Laurie-PC";
        Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("You connected to " + host);

        ChatClient = new A_Chat_Client(sock);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        out.println(UserName);
        out.flush();

        Thread X = new Thread(ChatClient);
        X.start();
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println(E);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server not responding");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant server side code?

Comment: could you post the whole Client code too? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the server code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.net.Socket;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class A_Chat_Server {

public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();

public static ArrayList<String> CurrentUsers = new ArrayList<String>();


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        final int port = 444;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
        A_Chat_Client_GUI.main(args);

        while (true) {
            Socket sock = server.accept();
            ConnectionArray.add(sock);

            System.out.println("Client connected from: " + sock.getLocalAddress().getHostName());

            AddUserName(sock);

            A_Chat_Server_Return chat = new A_Chat_Server_Return(sock);
            Thread X = new Thread(chat);
            X.start();


        }
    } catch (Exception X) {
        System.out.println(X);
    }

}

public static void AddUserName(Socket X) throws IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(X.getInputStream());
    String UserName = input.nextLine();
    CurrentUsers.add(UserName);

    for (int i = 0; i < A_Chat_Server.ConnectionArray.size(); i++) {
        Socket temp_sock = A_Chat_Server.ConnectionArray.get(i);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(temp_sock.getOutputStream());
        out.println("????1!!!!!!???######@22" + CurrentUsers);
        out.flush();
    }
}
}
```